# What US states celebrate an Independence Day?

Tags: united-states, independence

Today, March 2nd, is Texas Independence Day; a celebration of how the Texans officially declared independence from Mexico. I found that some other states (i.e. Rhode Island, Hawaii) do (or did) celebrate an Independence Day different from the national Independence Day on July 4<sup>th</sup>.

What states have their own Independence Day? And who do they celebrate independence from?

Comment: California does have an independence day, Hawaii was  conquered by Americans so if anything it would have a  "dependence " day.  Vermont wanted to be a state when it rebelled against England, but it's lands were claimed by ny and nh and couldn't join until that was worked out. The specific commemoration of this is not really emphasized like it is in Texas. None of the other states successful left other countries.

Comment: California may have an independence day, but I'm a native Californian, and have no clue when it might be, which should tell you how much it is celebrated.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Hawaii's independence day is May 28, going back to the kingdom's 1843 recognition by Britain and France.

Answer (score 1):

You might say that October 24, 1861 is [West Virginia's independence day](https://web.archive.org/web/20070307001222/http://www.wvculture.org/history/statehoo.html) from the rest of Virginia and from the Confederacy, by popular referendum in the portion of Virginia occupied by the Union.

Comment: It seems to me the questioner is more interested in what *other people* say are *Independence Day*s, not what they personally might or might not say are.